# How do I upload files to an external hard drive using terminal?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk

I'm currently trying to upload some files off of my device onto an external hard drive using Terminal, and I've run into some issues.

Using these steps: https://gist.github.com/kwcto/45e0b985071fad655e17

1. I've run the command `diskutil mount /dev/disk1s2`, which should allow me to read/write on the hard drive.
2. I used `cd /Volumes/<Hard Drive>` and `ls` to navigate onto the hard drive.
3. When running the command `mkdir Backup2021` (which should create a folder on the hard drive), I'm met with the error code
   `mkdir: Backup2021: Read-only file system`
4. I'm also unable to copy files from my device onto this external drive, as the walkthrough demonstrates.

This issue is constant over different devices; am I doing anything wrong, or is there an alternative route?

I'm mainly running macOS 10.12.6, but this issue has persisted on devices with different operating systems.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What filesystem is the external drive formatted with? Try running `diskutil info <Hard Drive>` to get information about the filesystem in use.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The drive is a Windows NT File System formatted as NTFS. Could there be a compatibility issue with the devices? The volume is marked as read-only.

Comment: Yes. Your external drive is formatted with NTFS filesystem. macOS does not natively support writing to NTFS drive. You'd need to install a driver to enable writing to NTFS drive.

Comment: Or re-format the drive with a compatible filesystem.